# Does returning "false" prevent bool function from further execution in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

example:

```
 function proceed() returns (bool success) {

if (msg.sender != owner) return false;

        return important_function();
    }
```

So important_function shouldn't be reached if msg.sender isn't owner (condition above returns false). This will give bad jump dest or revert, correct? Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does returning `false` prevent `bool` function from further execution in Solidity?

Returning any value prevents any function in (probably) every language from further execution.

> This will give bad jump dest or revert, correct?

No, not correct:

- `revert` and `require(<an expression which evaluates to false>)` will revert the transaction with a REVERT opcode
- `assert(<an expression which evaluates to false>)` and a few other scenarios (such as accessing an array at an illegal index) will revert the transaction with an INVALID opcode
- `return false` will **NOT** revert the transaction